# Ubuntu guest (running in VMware player) freezes on Windows Host

Tags: virtualbox, windows, google-chrome, virtualization, vmware

I am trying to run [Osboxes Ubuntu 20.4 guest image](https://www.osboxes.org/ubuntu/#ubuntu-20-04-4-vmware) on Windows 10 Home 22H2 (both 64 bit) host using VMware Workstation 17 Player. My host configuration is Core i7 1065G7, 16GB RAM and 1TB NVMe SSD.

This is how my host configuration looks:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I use only Chrome browser on host (also not too many tabs). But even with that use my Ubuntu freezes. I cannot even shutdown the Ubuntu. Why is that?

Comment: What is the percentage of RAM/CPU usage when Ubuntu freezes in Task manager?